# How to share internet over WiFi from wvdial in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet, wvdial

I have just installed 12.04 on a separate partition on my hard drive so I can dual-boot to either Windows 7 or Ubuntu.

I am living in Japan and so I'm using a mobile broadband USB device called "`Softbank C02LC`".

By default it seems that this device isn't recognized, so I did the following:

Terminal:

```
sudo su
nano /usr/bin/usbModemScript
```

Nano:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 1c9e 9900 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
```

Terminal:

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/usbModemScript
nano /etc/udev/rules.d/option.rules
```

Nano:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9900", RUN+="/usr/bin/usbModemScript"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="1c9e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9900", RUN+="/sbin/modprobe option"
```

which made the device visible from the network manager etc.

However, even though I set up my details correctly when I created a new connection (Correct username, APN etc) as soon as I try to connect it almost immediately disconnects.

Because of this I then followed the instructions at this [site](http://debugitos.main.jp/index.php?Ubuntu%2F%A5%E2%A5%D0%A5%A4%A5%EB%A5%A4%A5%F3%A5%BF%A1%BC%A5%CD%A5%C3%A5%C8).

And I ended up using the `c02lc_connect` script at the bottom of the page to connect to the Internet.

The file contains the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

usbinterfece=/dev/ttyUSB2
VID=1c9e
PID=9900
WRONG_PID=f000
LSUSB=/usr/sbin/lsusb
GREP=/bin/grep
MODPROBE=/sbin/modprobe
SWITCH=/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch
SWITCH_D=/etc/usb_modeswitch.d
WVDIAL=/usr/bin/wvdial
SLEEP=/bin/sleep
SUDO=/usr/bin/sudo
WHICH=/usr/bin/which

switch_config="$SWITCH_D/$VID:$WRONG_PID"

if ! [ -x $WVDIAL -a -x $SWITCH ]; then
    echo "Install wvdial and usb_modeswitch."
    exit 0
fi

check_usb() {
    local vid="$1"
    local pid="$2"
    ($LSUSB | $GREP "$vid:$pid")
}

if ! (check_usb "$VID" "$PID"); then
    echo "Cannot find modem device..."
    if (check_usb "$VID" "$WRONG_PID") && ( [ -f "$switch_config" ] ); then
        echo "The device is attached but its mode is wrong."
        echo "Try usb_modeswitch..."
        $SUDO $SWITCH -c "$switch_config"
        $SLEEP 1
        if (check_usb "$VID" "$PID"); then
            echo "Successfully switched the mode."
        else
            echo "Failed to switch the mode..."
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        exit 1
    fi
fi

if [ ! -c "$usbinterface" ]; then
    $SUDO $MODPROBE usbserial vendor=0x$VID product=0x$PID
    $SLEEP 2
fi

$SUDO $WVDIAL
```

which works completely fine - no problems what-so-ever.

But we also have 1 more laptop here which I need to share the Internet connection with.
In Windows 7 I do this with the `Connectify` program, and in Ubuntu I have seen that you can do things like set up hotspots etc.

But because I am using `WvDial` I am not sure how I would share the Internet.

I am only beginning to use Ubuntu but unfortunately until I can figure out how to share the Internet over WiFi when connected via `WvDial` I have to stick with Windows.

If you have any ideas on how to do this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you need to configure hostapd

I have configure following in hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf with WPA authentication options for wireless users

01 interface=wlan0

02 driver=nl80211

03 ssid=dontMessWithVincentValentine

04 hw_mode=g

05 channel=6

06 macaddr_acl=0

07 auth_algs=1

08 ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

09 wpa=3

10 wpa_passphrase=KeePGuessinG

11 wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK

12 wpa_pairwise=TKIP

13 rsn_pairwise=CCMP

sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I am new to Ubuntu so this might be a bit of a simple question, but I am assuming that I would need to edit the /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf file with my own settings and then should it just work if I create an ad hoc network?

Comment: yes u need to create a as hoc connection

Comment: Thank you - It's working now. At first it wasn't working even though I could see the ad hoc wireless connection, but that was just because of the encryption method for some reason, so I changed it to the WEP encryption and now it's fine.

Comment: Welcome its nice to to know that the problem is solved